# Increase Length of Stream Data from Client to Sharepoint Custom List

Tags: jquery, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to update a column in SharePoint 2013 Custom List but getting this error

> **The maximum number of bytes allowed to be read from the stream has been exceeded. After the last read operation, a total of 1049600 bytes has been read from the stream; however a maximum of 1048576 bytes is allowed.**

I am doing this operation using Json & Jquery POST Method.

how can i increase this limit of 1MB(1048576 Bytes)?

Comment: i am also facing same issue, do you got any solution?